# In `data.table` in R, is there a way to fast-assign values to rows based on an index?

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently working with a data.table table that has approximately 200 million rows.

```
>table
user     age
A        19
B        22
C        18
D        13
E        93
F        15
G        11
H        16
I        33
J        25
K        44
L        23
M        76
N        34
O        18
P        32
Q        55
```

Additionally, I have an "index" table that looks like:

```
> index
row_number     count
1              5
3              7
7              12
8              100
12             3
14             4
```

My goal is to be able to append the `count` column into `table`. The `row_number` column represents the rows numbers of `table`. Hence, when `row_number` equals 1, we append the value 5 to the user A and age 19 row of `table`. For `row_number` equals 3, we insert the value 7 to user C and age 18. There are gaps between, so I would like to fill them with 0.

So overall, I'd like:

```
>table
user     age    count 
A        19     5
B        22     0
C        18     7
D        13     0
E        93     0
F        15     0
G        11     12
H        16     100
I        33     0
J        25     0
K        44     0
L        23     3
M        76     0
N        34     4
O        18     0
P        32     0
Q        55     0
```

so far, my code for doing this is:

```
table[,count:= count, by=.N]
```

However, I am not able to get a correct sort. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this in `data.table`? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `set`

```
# set everything to 0
set(table, j = 'count', value = 0)
# replace the appropriate indices with the relevant values
set(table, j = 'count', i = index[['rownumber']], j = index[['count']])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `:=` operator. You don't need `by` here. Instead you could do it as:

```
table[, count := 0L][index$row_number, count := index$count]
```

First we initialise `count` with integer value `0`, and then for the row numbers given in `i`, we *modify* `count` of `table` *in-place* with the corresponding `count` values from `index`.

HTH

Comment: thanks so much, this is pure genius! on another note, I was wondering if there was a place I could find or create by myself the tar.gz version of data.table 1.9.3. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can download the zip version from the [project page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), unzip it, and use `R CMD BUILD`? In any case, Matt's already pushing `data.table 1.9.4` to CRAN, and it should be there sometime very soon.